# R dbWriteTable More Than One Class Warning

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, rodbc

I've had a working R script that uses the dbWriteTable command to write to a SQL Server table. It has worked well without issue for a while ... until the last few days.

Now when I run the dbWriteTable command, I get the following warning:

```
Found more than one class "blob" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'blob'
Also defined by ‘jsonlite’
```

Interestingly enough the table appears to write successfully.

Here is some sample code:

```
library("DBI")

db_test <- dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  driver = "SQL Server",
  server = "test_server",
  port = 1234,
  database = "test_db"
)

dbWriteTable(
  conn = db_test,
  name = SQL("dbo.swc_test_write_table"),
  value = df_test,
  overwrite = TRUE
)
```

I've tried explicitly naming the package, DBI::dbWriteTable, but it throws the same warning. For reference, I'm not using using the jsonlite package, but I have it installed.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Since `dbo` is default schema, try just passing table name without `SQL()` or `dbo.`

Comment: Getting the same error message starting today but with Snowflake instead of SQL Server.

Comment: @Parfait - Thanks for your response. I actually needed to add the SQL command recently because I noticed the table was not being written default schema. I noticed this happening recently, but not sure if it's a separate or related issue.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a DBI issue, but reported it upstream nevertheless: https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/376

Comment: https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/373 seems to be the right upstream bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, which is caused by the `jsonlite` package in its latest release 1.7.3.
See the bug report https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/373
It seems to be fixed upstream and as of now there's also an updated version available, [Changelog from 1.7.3 to 1.8.0](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/compare/v1.7.3...v1.8.0).

Comment: Thanks! Just updated to the latest version of jsonlite and no longer seeing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, seems to be interfering with encoding, possibly

EDIT:
Sorry for the "me too" post. I checked around a bit more and it's caused for me at least by the loading of the tidyverse library. Loading only DBI and odbc for me resolves the warning.

Comment: Alright, thank you Marco

Comment: I also had this problem. I am reading data from a database and added a call for a join on a table not in the database. I added the "copy=TRUE" argument to the join and this error appeared. I then replaced the library(tidyverse) call with calls for the packages I needed:  ggplot2, tidyr, stringr, and dplyr (odbc is loaded by another package). After that change, the problem went away.